# AngularJS Material ng-input-container resets time

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angularjs-material

My goal is to have a single model for date and time.

Unfortunately I haven't found a stable date-time-picker component for AngularJS Material, so I'm using two elements sharing same model: standard `md-datepicker` and regular `input type="time"`

```
      <md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDateTime" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <input ng-model="ctrl.myDateTime" type="time">
      </md-input-container>

      <span>Date and time chosen: {{ctrl.myDateTime}}</span>
```

Firstly, I choose date. Once date is chosen, `ctrl.myDateTime` gets date value with `00:00:00` time (in browser time zone) that is displayed in `span`.
Then I choose time. When time is set, it's displayed in `span` correctly as well.

The issue here: each time `input type="time"`  losts focus (like `onblur`), for some reason time fraction is resetted to `00:00:00`, but `input` keeps displaying the user's value.

And that's where I need help.
The only thing that I figured out is if `input` is not wraped with `md-input-container` then time is resetted only once, and if I change it again, focus lost doesn't reset time.

How to avoid that?

Code sample to reproduce:
https://codepen.io/mih-kopylov/pen/KKMxgBK

Comment: I tried your link. Appears to work without error. Maybe I’m misunderstanding your problem. 

Set date works. Set time works. Using mobile browser safari. Maybe it’s a browser issue?

Comment: @tbone849 that's odd. I've opened the link once again and the bug is reproduced. I'm using Chrome desktop (latest). Here's a link with video recorded (live till 30.11.2020) https://yadi.sk/i/JAP1f93pTBbWrg

Comment: I've also did the same in Chrome on Android, and in Firefox Desktop. Same thing is reproduced.
The issue is reproducing once time input losts its focus.

Comment: I see the issue now. That is strange.

Comment: Have you given this a try https://beenote.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/

Comment: Thanks, @tbone849, interesting thing. I'll take a look.

Comment: If you put both (md-datepicker and input) in the same md-input-container, the input is reset only once.

Comment: @FrançoisB. good point, thanks. But why is it resetted at all - that's the question?

Answer (score 0):

By changing the type from `time` to `datetime` you avoid this.
If you want to have only the `time`, you need an additional variable for it.

```html
<md-content ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" layout-padding="" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout="column">
    <div flex="">
      <md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDateTime" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
<!-- when time is changed using input inside md-input-container, time is resetted on blur -->
        <input ng-model="ctrl.myDateTime" type="datetime">
      </md-input-container>
<!-- when time is changed using this input, time is resetted but only once -->
      <input ng-model="ctrl.myDateTime" type="datetime">
    </div>
    <span>Date and time chosen: {{ctrl.myDateTime}}</span>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

If you choose to separate the date and the time, you can use a function with:

```js
myDate.setTime(myTime.getTime());
```

Comment: That's not how it worked several versions of Angular Material ago. I've updated version, and faced this issue. And I don't need to have datetime because I want to leverage material datepicker component for date. So I would like to find the reason why it stops working and figure out if I can fix that before using another component